# Configurar servidor IIS8 y Glassfish (Payara server)

Tags: servidor, iis, glassfish, payara

Tengo un problema que es el siguiente: se tiene instalado dos servidores uno que  payara server para un sitio web que esta escrito en jsp, estamos bien, y IIS 8 para  otros sitios aspx.

El inconveniente es que la ip publica solo me esta tomando el servidor payara server, el IIS antes se trabaja en local pero ahora necesitamos que uno de los sitios arrojados allí sean visto desde la ip publica pero me genera conflicto ¿Cómo hago para que el IIS también sea accesible desde publica?

Ya al payara server le cambié el puerto por el cual se comunicaba con el router y le puse otro pero cuando lo trato de iniciar me aparece siempre ese ¿Cómo haría en ese caso? más que todo que la ip publica funcione con los dos servidores web o por lo menos que me deje por el IIS.

Comment: Intenta cambiando los puertos que usa uno de ellos por default

Comment: Ya lo hice, cambie los puertos del payara server y efectivamente no me da conexion pero tampoco se conecta IIS